Finding the coefficients of a general solution to an homogeneous ODE via Sturm-Liouville theory
Say we've got a Sturm-Liouville problem in canonical form,
$$x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)+y=-\lambda y, \ \text{with}\ \ y(1)=y(e)=0\text{ and } 1\leq x\leq e .$$
From here we can deduce the differential operator
$$\mathcal L\equiv x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)+1,$$
and its weight
$$w(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$$
This problem can be solved by substituting $x=e^t$ and we'd get
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}A_n\sin(n\pi\ln x),$$
where the eigenvalues are
$$\lambda_n=n^2\pi^2-1$$
for $n=1,2,3,...$
The actual question comes here:
Now, say for the same contour conditions they ask us to solve
$$x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)+y=1.$$
Since the differential operator is the same one, we have that
$$\mathcal L y=-\lambda y=1,$$
meaning
$$1=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n A_n\sin(n\pi\ln x)$$
From here on I don't really know how to proceed. Maybe I should multiply by $\sin(m\pi\ln x)$ and integrate from $1$ to $e$ (computing $\langle 1|\sin(m\pi\ln x)\rangle$ and $\langle \sin(n\pi\ln x)|\sin(m\pi\ln x)\rangle\propto\delta_{nm}$) since they form an orthogonal space and hope to isolate $A_n$? Also, when is it more convenient to normalize the general solution, previous to calculating the inner products or after having found the coefficients?

$\mathbf{ATTEMPT\ AT\ FINISHING\ THE\ PROBLEM:}$
As I said, now we'll try multiplying both sides by the weight $1/x$ and another eigenfunction $\sin(m\pi\ln x)$ from the same basis ($m=1,2,3,...$) and then integrating on both sides from $1$ to $e$. On the LHS we'll have
$$\langle 1|\sin(m\pi\ln x)\rangle=\int_1^e1\cdot\sin(m\pi\ln x)\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{x}=\int_0^1\sin(m\pi t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{1-\cos(m\pi)}{m\pi}=\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m\pi}$$
and on the RHS,
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle-\lambda y|\sin(m\pi\ln x)\rangle&=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_n A_n\langle\sin(n\pi\ln x)|\sin(m\pi\ln x)\rangle\\
&=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_n A_n\int_1^e\sin(n\pi\ln x)\sin(m\pi\ln x)\,\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}\\
&=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_n A_n\int_0^1\sin(n\pi t)\sin(m\pi t)\,\mathrm dt\\
&=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_n A_n\frac{\delta_{nm}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}A_m\lambda_m\\
\end{aligned}$$
Equating both sides of the equation we get
$$\frac{1-(-1)^m}{m\pi}=\frac{1}{2}A_m\lambda_m\iff A_m=\frac{2(1-(-1)^m)}{m\pi(m^2\pi^2-1)}$$
Therefore, the general solution to the proposed problem is
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n\pi(n^2\pi^2-1)}\sin(n\pi\ln x)$$
I don't know if it is mandatory to normalize, maybe it's useful when computing the inner products, but the normalized general solution should look like
$$\hat y(x)=\frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{\langle y\,|\,y\rangle}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\sqrt 2(1-(-1)^n)}{n\pi(n^2\pi^2-1)}\sin(n\pi\ln x)$$
One could even express the solution in odd indexes because $1-(-1)^m=0$ for even $m$:
$$\hat y(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{4\sqrt 2}{(2k-1)\pi[(2k-1)^2\pi^2-1]}\sin[(2k-1)\pi\ln x]$$

The name is Sturm, not Stürm.

You are on the right track (but don't forget to multiply also by the weight $1/x$).

Am I missing something? Or is this the solution?

HINT: Let $y(x)=Y(\ln x)$, which is equivalent to $Y(x)=y(e^x)$. Then $y'(x)=Y'(\ln x)\frac{1}{x}$, so that $xy'(x)=Y'(\ln x)$. This gives an equivalent equation
$$
      x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+y=-\lambda y \\
       Y''(\ln x)+Y(\ln x) = -\lambda Y(\ln x) \\
          Y''(\ln x)=-(\lambda+1)Y(\ln x) \\
         Y(w)=A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda+1} w)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda+1}w) \\
         y(x)=A\sin(\sqrt{\lambda+1}\ln x)+B\cos(\sqrt{\lambda+1}\ln x).
$$
Hopefully that will get you started.

The problem in question is obtaining the coefficients of the general solution, not how to solve the ODE. Thank you though.

@JoanS.GuillametF. :  The eigenfunctions of the Sturm-LIouville system form a complete orthogonal basis, and that gives you the expansion.
